# How do I get a label on the same line as a Datebox input field?

Tags: html, css, datebox

This is embarrasing. Im making use of the [Datebox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/) module and I'm trying to align a label next to an input just like the examples in the provided link.

I'm expecting something along the lines of this:
[image]

but get this:
[image]

This is from my HTML:

```
<div name="activities" id="activities">
       <label for="activity-1">Activity 1</label>
       <input name="activity-1" id="activity-1" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "durationflipbox", "overrideDurationOrder": ["h","i"], "overrideDurationFormat": "%Dl:%DM"}'/>
</div>
```

I've tried setting styles in the CSS

```
#activities {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: right;
}
```

but I'm not getting the expected result given above.

**What am I doing wrong?**

UPDATE
It seems that HTML is being inserted when loading the page so the final result looks like this:
[image]

I apologize for inserting an image instead of code, but I can't seem to copy the HTML in a legible way.

Anyway, here it is if you want to copy/paste it:

```
<div name="activities" id="activities">
        <label for="activity-1" class="ui-input-text" style="vertical-align: middle;">Activity 1</label>
        <div class="ui-input-text ui-shadow-inset ui-corner-all ui-btn-shadow ui-body-c"><div class="ui-input-datebox ui-corner-all ui-body-c" style="border: none;"><input name="activity-1" id="activity-1" type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options="{&quot;mode&quot;: &quot;durationflipbox&quot;, &quot;overrideDurationOrder&quot;: [&quot;h&quot;,&quot;i&quot;], &quot;overrideDurationFormat&quot;: &quot;%Dl:%DM&quot;}" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c" readonly="readonly"><a href="#" class="ui-input-clear ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext" title="Open Date Picker" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Open Date Picker</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-grid ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></span></a></div></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The label is displaying inline for me on Chrome. Check out the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ua4Gs/.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm also on Chrome, but get a different result. It seems the sourced javascript files belonging to the module are inserting HTML when the page is loaded. I'll update my question.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with all the external resources that you are using? (The plugin files...)

Comment: Yep, I get the same result as in my browser. See my updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realised it is due to jQuery Mobile CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/Lera/HEeHd/ 
What browser are you using?

I can also get the same results without the CSS.  Just your HTML:

```
<div name="activities" id="activities">
       <label for="activity-1">Activity 1</label>
       <input name="activity-1" id="activity-1" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "durationflipbox", "overrideDurationOrder": ["h","i"],     "overrideDurationFormat": "%Dl:%DM"}'/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set some styles to your label like this:

```
#activities label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gzQKG/2/)

Comment: That might work, but I have to take into account the HTML above the div that I haven't shown here to keep it as simple as possible. Also won't I get into trouble with absolute positions? It's suppose to work on Chrome and Safari. Mobile and Desktop.